# c# console calculator outputs numbers into ascii

Tags: c#, console, ascii, console-application, calculator

So as one of the things to test myself on I was thinking to create a calculator; I know that it keeps on changing my numbers to ASCII, what I'm not EXACTLY sure is how to stop it, here's my code and I hope I'm not being too greatly dumb about it.

```
        char operation;
        String calculation;
        double num1, num2, ans;


        Console.WriteLine("Place your calculation in the form (x'symbol'y)");
        calculation = Console.ReadLine();
        num1 = calculation[0];
        num2 = calculation[2];
        operation = calculation[1];

        switch (operation)

            case '+':
                ans = num1 + num2;
                Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
                break;
            case '-':
                ans = num1 - num2;
                Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
                break;
            case '/':
                ans = num1 / num2;
                Console.WriteLine(num1 / num2);
                break;
            case '*':
                ans = num1 * num2;
                Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2);
                break;
```

I know some of the braces are gone, it's supposed to do simple calculations like 1+2 or 3*7, only one digit calculations.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Stop it, but what?

Comment: Rather than doubles, you almost certainly want to use `decimal`, just as an aside...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead when getting your value from Console.ReadLine:

```
num1 = double.Parse(calculation[0].ToString());
num2 = double.Parse(calculation[2].ToString());
```

You'll notice the type of value you get from calculation[0] is a string, not an integer, so that right now, when you do num1 + num2, its just adding the strings together (concatenating) rather than adding the values as integers.

The call to 'ToString()' after is necessary as double.Parse cannot be called with a char - this use case is probably is not the best use for double however, and you might have a better fit (the way it is now) using int.

Comment: Right it makes total sense, and that's what I intially did, yet you can't convert a char to a string.

Comment: Shouln't be any issue calling a char `ToString()` - as the below works fine:

`char x = 'a';`
`string y = x.ToString();`

Comment: No my mistake it worked perfectly fine, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Double.TryParse` to convert from string to number.

Answer (score 0):

Convert values to integers, calculate answer and print it. For example, for operation '+', it will be:

```
var ans = Convert.ToInt32(calculation[0]) + Convert.ToInt32(calculation[2]);
Console.WriteLine(ans);
```